# Using the same instance of an object as the argument and as the calling object in calling a function

Tags: c++, oop

I wrote a small program for an assignment in an object-oriented C++ class in which I had to write a function which displayed the magnitude of a complex number. It works when written this way and I know how to write it without arguments in the parameter, but I want to know if there is a functional problem with the code (the calling object and the argument are the same object).

```
// displays the magnitude of a complex number
void Complex::magnitude(Complex c) const {
    cout << "\nMagnitude of "; c.display(); cout << " = ";

cout.precision(3); cout.setf(std::ios::fixed, std::ios::floatfield);
cout << sqrt(pow(static_cast<double>(c.real), 2) + 
            (pow(static_cast<double>(c.imag), 2)) ) << "\n";
} // end function magnitude
```

Here's the redundant part with c1 as the calling object and argument:

```
c1.magnitude(c1);
```

I know how to write this code without c1 as an argument for magnitude() and that all I have to do is delete the argument and delete "c." from the function and it will still work the same. My question is simply *Is this be a problem functionally when a program is written like this?*

Comment: Is there a compelling reason for this to be a member function? Also, do you need to make a local copy of the argument?

Comment: Because the professor wanted it as a member function (it's an OOP class). I know I didn't need to make a local copy. I wrote it this way originally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code makes syntactically no sense. Either use a member function taking no argument, or a free-standing function with argument (or both).

```
namespace My {
  struct Complex {
    void magnitude() const;  // member function
     ...
  };
  void magnitude(Complex const&); // free-standing function
}
```

These can be used like this

```
My::Complex c1;
c1.magnitude();
magnitude(c1);
```

(However, using the name `magnitude` for a function not returning the magnitude is dangerous and therefore bad practice, better call it `print_magnitude_to_stdout()`.)

Comment: I rewrote it with no argument. And thanks for the tip on renaming the function.

Comment: Always use descriptive function and variable names. Makes code much easer to read and documentation redundant. Btw, did you know that there is `std::complex<>` ? no need to re-invent the wheel...

Comment: I didn't know that, but this was for an assignment. If I needed to do this for practical programming or for work, I would have immediately looked to see if someone already wrote a method for complex numbers.

Comment: If the assignment was about C++, then it was rather pointless, since with C++ one would use `std::complex<>`.

Comment: I know there is. The point is to learn object-oriented programming, not rewrite features that were already in place.

Answer (score 2):

This will not be a problem functionally, but logically if the function must take an object as an argument, you should make this function `static`.

In addition, since you are not modifying the incoming object, you should make the argument `const`. Finally, since copying the object may be more expensive than copying a reference, you may want to change the argument to be passed by reference.

```
static void Complex::magnitude(const Complex &c);

...

Complex myComplex(...);
Complex::magnitude(myComplex);
```

Comment: Is there a reason this way might be better than a parameterless member function, as NPE said? (He also recommended the way you just described as another alternative.)

Comment: @btalbot The decision is entirely up to you, the designer of your program. If you think that the parameterless `magnitude` would make more sense to the readers of your code, go for it; if you are certain that you must pass `Complex` as a parameter, than that is up to you as well. This approach may be useful for passing `Complex::magnitude` as a function pointer to something that expects a function that takes `Complex` as an argument.

Answer (score 2):

Functionally your code is OK, with one caveat: your function takes its argument by value, and therefore relies on the copy constructor. If the copy ctor is fine, your code is fine; otherwise, it may not be.

Stylistically, I find this code objectionable. It should either be a parameterless member function, or a one-argument `static` function (taking its argument by `const` reference).

Comment: Thanks. I chose the former (a parameterless member function).